# Making Spring beans behave like ThreadLocal instances for an ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

In my web application, I have a background service. This service uses Generator class that contains an Engine class and an `ExecutorService` configured to use multiple threads and that accepts GeneratorTasks.

```
@Component
public class Generator {
    @Autowired
    private Engine heavyEngine;

    private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    //I actually pass the singleton instance Generator class into the task.
    public void submitTask(TaskModel model, TaskCallback callback) {
        this.exec.submit(new GeneratorTask(model, this, callback));
    }
}

@Component
public class Engine {
    public Engine() {
        //time-consuming initialization code here
    }
}

public class GeneratorTask implements Callable<String> {
    public GeneratorTask(TaskModel m, Generator g, ReceiptCallback c) {
        this.m = m;
        this.generator = g;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {
        //This actually calls the Engine class of the generator.
        //Maybe I should have passed the Engine itself?
        this.generator.runEngine(c);  
    }
}
```

The Engine class takes a long time to initialize so I ideally want to initialize it only once per thread. I can't just make it a singleton instance because the instance can't be shared across multiple threads (it relies on sequential processing). It's perfectly fine to reuse the instance though, after a processing task has completed.

I was thinking of making the `private Engine heavyEngine` variable a ThreadLocal variable. However, I'm also new to Spring so I was wondering if there might be another way to inject ThreadLocal variables using Spring annotations. I've looked at scoping the bean to `request` scope, but I'm not sure how I should go about it given my design.

Any guidance on how to improve my design would be appreciated.

Comment: Since `Engine` is autowired I assume you have declared it as a bean. By default Spring beans are singleton, so there is a good chance that you `Engine` is already a singleton...

Comment: Sorry I might have been unclear. My problem is, I can't make Engine a singleton because due to its processing logic, it can't be accessed by multiple concurrent threads. It's safe to reuse the Engine once a complete 'job' has been done, which is why I was thinking of making an instance per thread that uses it.

Comment: I understand, I was saying that with your current code Engine is already a singleton, even if it's not what you want it's what your code is actually doing.

Comment: Ah, I see. I already realized that- actually my current implementation is just using a `singleThreadExecutor` so I don't run into any concurrency issues. I'm just looking for other ways to implement a ThreadLocal-like behavior for this design. =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all abandon `ThreadLocal` - there is something scary in that class. What you need is just object pooling. It's not well known feature, but Spring supports this as well:

```
<bean id="engineProto" class="Engine" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true"/>

<bean id="engine" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.aop.target.CommonsPoolTargetSource">
            <property name="targetClass" value="Engine"/>
            <property name="targetBeanName" value="engineProto"/>
            <property name="maxSize" value="3"/>
            <property name="maxWait" value="5000"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now when you inject `engine`, you'll actually receive proxy object (`Engine` will need an interface) that will delegate all calls to free object in the pool. Pool size is configurable. Of course there is nothing preventing you from using [`ThreadLocalTargetSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/target/ThreadLocalTargetSource.html) which uses `ThreadLocal` instead of [Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/). Both approaches guarantee exclusive, thread safe access to `Engine`.

Finally you can use pooling manually (but the beauty of solution above is that it's completely transparent) or switch to EJBs, which are pooled by definition.

Comment: Classloader memory leaks are kinda scary.

Comment: So you can inject the "engine" bean into anywhere expecting an Engine interface instance? Does it just create an anonymous class that inherits from the Engine interface that uses pooling behind-the-scenes?

Answer (score 5):

FYI, Spring 3.0 and later includes a thread-backed Scope implementation, [SimpleThreadScope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html).

In order to use it you need to register a custom scope:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="thread">
                <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then to declare a thread-scoped bean:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.foo.MyBean" scope="thread">
    ...
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have created a factory for `Engine` and call it inside `GeneratorTask`. By this way you can remove the `heavyEngine` field inside `Generator` and the `Generator` constructor argument in `GeneratorTask`.
Then if you want to save the initialization time of `Engine` you can still declare it as a singleton but use the `synchronized` keyword on non thread safe methods.

```
public class Generator {    
    @Autowired private EngineFactory engineFactory;
    private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public void submitTask(TaskModel model, TaskCallback callback) {
        this.exec.submit(new GeneratorTask(engineFactory, model, callback));
    }
}

public class EngineFactory {
    @Autowired private Engine instance;

    public Engine getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}

public class Engine {
    public Engine() {
        //time-consuming initialization code here
    }

    public synchronized void runEngine() {
        // Do non thread safe stuf
    } 
}

public class GeneratorTask implements Callable<String> {
    public GeneratorTask(EngineFactory f, TaskModel m, ReceiptCallback c) {
        this.f = f;
        this.m = m;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {
        Engine engine = f.getInstance();
        engine.runEngine();
        ... 
    }
}
```

There is probably a pure Spring way to pass the engine to the Callable but in this case the factory is good enough in my opinion.